# JavaScript for Acrobat API

Tags: javascript, adobe

I am sorry this might sound very naive. I am trying to use the Javascript for Acrobat Api, but how exactly to I reference this in a web page? Maybe I missed something. Does it have to be done via Server Side code? I am really finding it hard to understand how to start. The documentation is all about a console, but I just need a pointer where to start. I am quite good with javascript, so this is not about that. I just needed to know where to start

Comment: Come on people. If i use an API, I reference a script. I cannot find a script that I should reference. can You at least what I want before you down vote? English is not really my first language and I might be failing to articulate my question. But it is not helping to just down vote.

Comment: Ok. My apologies. I am trying to edit a pdf document using that Adobe Javascript API. I know c# and javascript. When i look at the API, I see code that looks like Javascript, as the documentation says. However, I suppose I need to reference some javascript file from Adobe, like when using google maps, to create this object they keep refering to. However, I cant seem to find this Adobe script ..or maybe, I am missing something. Hope that is clear?

Comment: Tell you what, let me just try and figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat JavaScript is not related to web-based JS, except that they both share the same core syntax and objects. The Acrobat JS has its own set of objects, methods and properties that can't be used in a web-page, and vice-versa.

If you explain what exactly you're trying to do I could offer additional help.
I also recommend the tutorials on this site: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/